# Smallest number can't be made with linear combination of unique positive integers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, programming

I'm given a set of numbers, let's say {2, 6, 9}. I have to find smallest number `greater than` largest number in the set, which can't be represented as linear combination of numbers in the set.

In other words, an integer x such that `x = c1*2 + c2*6 + c3*9` has a solution and x is closest to the largest number in the set. For this set, there's no such answer. In the example give, there's no such smallest integer since every integer > 9 can be represented as linear sum of these three.

What's the general answer ?

Comment: depends on greatest common divisor

Comment: Are the coefficients positive?

Comment: I actually think of the Chinese Remainder Theorem

Comment: @Mythomorphic Yes. all coefficients are positive, including zero.

Comment: This is the [coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem)  There is a nice solution when you only have two numbers, not when you have more.  In your case you would just have to check the numbers above the largest until the coin problem solution for the two smallest.

Comment: But for the case I've given, there's no solution. So, how do you upper bound the iteration ?